# Handle ToastNotification in WIndows Phone 8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to Use `WNS with Windows Phone 8.1 (SilverLight)` platform. And I am successfully getting the notification on my client App. But I am stuck at intercepting the Click/Tap on Toast Notification.

Attempt :-

```
public async void Initilialize()
{
    channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

    channel.PushNotificationReceived += PushNotificationReceived;
}

void PushNotificationReceived(PushNotificationChannel sender, PushNotificationReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    DispatcherInvoker.Invoke(() => MessageBox.Show("Notifacation recieved")                     );
}
```

But i am not able to see the Message when i tap on the Toast Notification and my app is launching successfully when i tap on toast.

does anybody know about what i am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, It is my fault though, This **PushNotificationReceived** will only hit when your app is running and you got the notification during this time.